# Typescript in ramda is suddenly giving an error

Tags: typescript, ramda.js

I got this typescript error on production when I build my project (reactjs starter + typescript)

```
TypeScript error: Argument of type '<T>(list: readonly Record<"dataField", T>[]) => T[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(x: K extends readonly (infer U)[] ? U[] : K extends Dictionary<infer U> ? Dictionary<U> : never) => {}[]'.
  Types of parameters 'list' and 'x' are incompatible.
    Type 'K extends readonly (infer U)[] ? U[] : K extends Dictionary<infer U> ? Dictionary<U> : never' is not assignable to type 'readonly Record<"dataField", {}>[]'.
      Type '(K extends Dictionary<infer U> ? Dictionary<U> : never) | {}[]' is not assignable to type 'readonly Record<"dataField", {}>[]'.
        Type 'K extends Dictionary<infer U> ? Dictionary<U> : never' is not assignable to type 'readonly Record<"dataField", {}>[]'.
          Type 'Dictionary<{}>' is missing the following properties from type 'readonly Record<"dataField", {}>[]': length, concat, join, slice, and 18 more.
            Type 'Dictionary<any>' is not assignable to type 'readonly Record<"dataField", {}>[]'.
              Type 'any[] | Dictionary<any>' is not assignable to type 'readonly Record<"dataField", {}>[]'.
                Type 'Dictionary<any>' is missing the following properties from type 'readonly Record<"dataField", {}>[]': length, concat, join, slice, and 18 more.  TS2345

    261 | export const getColumnsToGroup = R.pipe(
    262 |   R.filter(R.propEq('summarize', false)),
  > 263 |   R.map(R.prop('dataField'))
        |   ^
    264 | );
    265 |
    266 | export const groupBimInstances = (columnsToGroup: IBootstrapTableColumnConfig[]) => R.pipe(
```

I don't get this error on my development machine. I deployed many times and this suddenly occured today.

Don't really know what it's about.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are the versions of TypeScript and all the compilation flags the same between your machine and the build machine?

Comment: I run yarn build both on production and development. Tsconfig.json is same. Typescript version is read from package.json.

Comment: are you using a *lock file* for your deps? Try to delete your *node_modules* and your package manager cache... and then install everything again :)

Answer (score 1):

this works just fine for me...

```js
interface Thing {
  summarize: boolean;
  dataField: string;
}

const foo = R.pipe<Thing[], Thing[], string[]>(
  R.filter(R.propEq('summarize', false)),
  R.pluck('dataField'),
);

foo([
  { summarize: false, dataField: 'hello world' },
  { summarize: true, dataField: 'hello galaxy' },
  { summarize: true, dataField: 'hello universe' },
]);
```

- not that `R.map(R.prop('dataField'))` is equal to `R.pluck('dataField')`
- if you don't explicitly pass types to `R.pipe`, your pipe will output `unknown[]`.